# Django Template Syntax Error in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates

I tried launching my Google App Engine app on localhost, and got a Django error I am stuck on.

"TemplateSyntaxError: Template 'base/_base.html' cannot be extended, because it doesn't exist"

I put the templates in a /templates, and then _base.html & index.html in /templates/base . Thanks!
Emile @ [proudn00b.com](http://proudn00b.com)

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 511, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/Users/emilepetrone/code/thebuswheel/main.py", line 65, in get
    outstr = template.render(temp, { 'path': path })
….

…..
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 58, in get_parent
    raise TemplateSyntaxError, "Template %r cannot be extended, because it doesn't exist" % parent
TemplateSyntaxError: Template 'base/_base.html' cannot be extended, because it doesn't exist
```

Referring to :

def get(self):

```
    path = self.request.path

    temp = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        'templates' + path)

    if not os.path.isfile(temp):
        temp = os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(__file__),
            'templates/base/index.html')

    outstr = template.render(temp, { 'path': path })        
    self.response.out.write(outstr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to look in your templates. The important part of the traceback is at the end:

Template 'base/_base.html' cannot be extended, because it doesn't exist

Do you have a template named 'base/_base.html'? If not, find what other template file is trying to extend it.

Comment: I do have the base/_base.html file, & that is the only template file. Def part of the frustration

Comment: maybe it would help to show your template and the yaml config file. :-)

Comment: The files were too long for stackoverflow so I posted them on the blog ...

http://www.proudn00b.com/post/976956081/buswheel-files-4-error

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can double check is to make sure one of the paths in the TEMPLATE_DIRS setting points to the root directory for your templates.

Also make sure it's a full absolute path in the setting, not relative to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @jps

rename base/_base.html to just base.html, no subdir. Update index.html with new path.